# Query uses Primary Key Index instead of Nonclustered index defined

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this simple query and I am confused why the index is not working.

```
SELECT lop.RecordID ProspectusID,
    c.c_code CourseCode,
    c.c_desc CourseDescription,
    COALESCE(c.c_major, '') MajorName,
    lop.EffectiveYear EffectiveSchoolYear,
    COALESCE(COUNT(pc.ProspectusID), 0) SubjectCount
FROM dbo.ListOfProspectus AS lop
    INNER JOIN dbo.courselist AS c ON lop.CourseCode = c.c_code
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProspectusContent AS pc ON lop.RecordID = pc.ProspectusID -- <== problem
WHERE lop.CourseCode IN ('BSIT')
GROUP BY lop.RecordID, c.c_code, c.c_desc, c.c_major, lop.EffectiveYear
ORDER BY CourseCode, EffectiveSchoolYear
```

which generates the following plan,

[image]
[image]

I have an index defined on `dbo.ProspectusContent.ProspectusID`.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_ProspectusContent_prospectusid] 
ON [dbo].[ProspectusContent]
(
    [ProspectusID] ASC
)
```

But why is it still using the primary key index?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProspectusContent] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [ProspectusContent_pk_RecordID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordID] ASC
)
```

If I remove the following computed column: `COALESCE(COUNT(pc.ProspectusID), 0) SubjectCount` in the `SELECT` clause, the server generates this plan:

[image]

**UPDATE**

However, when I try to execute a query on table `dbo.ProspectusContent` alone, it uses the nonclustered index,

```
SELECT ProspectusID
FROM dbo.ProspectusContent AS pc 
WHERE pc.ProspectusID = 2
```

[image]
[image]

By the way, `idx_ProspectusContent_prospectusid` is the same with `idx_dmcasarms_ProspectusContent_prospectusid`, *just convention name policy*.

If there's anything missing detail in my question, please do me so I can update it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table only has 2 rows. The cost difference between a table scan and an NC seek is negligible. SQL Server is pretty good about finding the cheapest way to getting things done. I'd expect that when the table gets bigger, the NC index will start getting used.

To compare performance, you can force the index to be used with an index hint:

```
SELECT lop.RecordID ProspectusID,
    c.c_code CourseCode,
    c.c_desc CourseDescription,
    COALESCE(c.c_major, '') MajorName,
    lop.EffectiveYear EffectiveSchoolYear,
    COALESCE(COUNT(pc.ProspectusID), 0) SubjectCount
FROM dbo.ListOfProspectus AS lop
    INNER JOIN dbo.courselist AS c ON lop.CourseCode = c.c_code
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ProspectusContent AS pc WITH (INDEX(idx_ProspectusContent_prospectusid)) ON lop.RecordID = pc.ProspectusID
WHERE lop.CourseCode IN ('BSIT')
GROUP BY lop.RecordID, c.c_code, c.c_desc, c.c_major, lop.EffectiveYear
ORDER BY CourseCode, EffectiveSchoolYear
```

In production, I would use the hint as a last resort though. Given proper indexes and statistics, the query optimizer can typically build the cheapest plan on its' own.

Read more about hints: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I thought the number of records won't matter since I tested a query on the table only and it performs `Index Seek`. But when I generated test data on it, it performs well. Sorry for ignorance.